# how to remove empty lines at the end of excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

I compiled an excel utility to split a huge file into smaller files, in my case 100k rows . However, the last file is showing 100k rows though the data is not there till 100k rows. How can I remove the blank lines at the end of the file for the last partition.

Here is my code.

```
   Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(filePath) 

  'Initialize data  
   Set ThisSheet = objWorkbook.ActiveSheet

  'Getting number of columns and rows for calculation
   NumOfColumns = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
   rowCount = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count  

   WorkbookCounter = 1
   RowsInFile = 100000      

     If rowCount > 100000 Then
      ' extracting the file name alone.
       fName = Left(fileName, (InStrRev(fileName, ".") - 1)) ' file name  
      ' Copy the data of the first row (header)
      Set RangeOfHeader = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(1, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(1, NumOfColumns))

     'Create the file system object for creating folders
     Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")    

    'extracting the path name excluding the file name
     newPath = CStr(Left(filePath, InStrRev(filePath, "\")))     
     folderName = newPath & "Copy_of_" & fName & "\"     
     'Create the folders using objFSO
     'First check if folders exists and create only they dont exist
     if Not objFSO.FolderExists(folderName) Then      
       objFSO.CreateFolder(folderName)
     Else
       WScript.Echo "Folder already Exists"
   End If
```

when I select Ctrl+Shift+down arrow.. count shows file. When I click Ctrl+End button.. control goes to 100kth row ...and many of the rows above are blank. Ideally Ctrl+End should stop where the data ends.

pointers are very much appreciated and many thanks in advance.

Comment: the cells probably contain spaces or non printing characters.  You could test your data those situations and not right them.  or conversely identify where the end of data is and only write to the end of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not 100% sure but i belive this will count empty rows that are allocated in the excel file.

```
rowCount = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Try using this instead:

```
Sheets("Sheetname").Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Hi @Odatas, I am getting runtime error when trying to do the same.          `Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(filePath) 
 
       'Initialize data  
       Set ThisSheet = objWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  
       'Getting number of columns and rows for calculation
       NumOfColumns = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
       'rowCount = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count  
       Set sht = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
       MsgBox sht
       LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, sCOL).End(xlUp).Row
       MsgBox "last row is --->" & LastRow`

Comment: Did you define the `xlUP` constant in your code? `Const xlUp = -4162`

Comment: Hi @Theo, yes, when I declared that constant, it worked. thanks a lot